# Java - Get the last directory in hierarchy in a path

Tags: java, io, path

I have the path: `"C:\DirA\DirB\DirC"`.
I'm looking for a way to get `DirC` (as string) which is the last one in this path hierarchy.
I don't want to use String manipulations like `lastIndexOf` or a like to avoid platform related path separators (The path separator is `\` for windows and `/` for linux) so it better be some `Path` functionality..

Answer (score 4):

```
Paths.get("C:\\DirA\\DirB\\DirC").getFileName()
```

Comment: Note that `"C:\DirA\DirB\DirC"` won't compile due to illegal escapes; you would need `"C:\\DirA\\DirB\\DirC"`. Could also do `Paths.get("C:", "DirA", "DirB", "DirC")`.

Comment: Sorry about it. I've just copy string from the question. Fixed